# How to find the amount paid for a ticket?

Tags: air-travel, usa, tickets

I'm trying to find out the cost of a flight that my daughter took on June 9, 2015.

Where can I get this information? I tried going to the airline's site, but it was no help.

Comment: Who paid for the ticket? And *why* do you want to know the cost? Without this information, there's little anyone can do to help.

Answer (score 11):

If you have access to the airline/travel agent account on which the ticket was bought, you may be able to find it under the previous purchases there. Likewise, if you have access to the bank account or credit card that was used to pay, the information will be one of the statements at around the relevant time.

If you don't have access to any of those accounts, you won't be able to find out what the ticket cost. Because airlines use [dynamic pricing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_pricing), the price of a ticket can change from minute to minute. You'd have to know the exact time at which the ticket was bought to even have a chance to know what it cost.  However, I doubt that any airline would release sufficiently detailed pricing information for past tickets to allow you to work out the actual cost: that would give away a lot of commercially sensitive information about their pricing algorithm.

So, ultimately, the answer is that you should ask your daughter what the ticket cost and, if she doesn't want to tell you, then you'll have to accept that you don't know.

Comment: "So, ultimately, the answer is that you should ask your daughter what the ticket cost and, if she doesn't want to tell you, then you'll have to accept that you don't know." This should probably be the answer regardless of whether this information is possible to obtain, unless she owes you money and you suspect she is lying about her ability to pay you back or something.

Answer (score 1):

These are few ways you can find the price you paid:

- Look at your credit/debit card statements.
- Search email notifications of the purchase.
- Log into the portal where you purchased the ticket from (assuming you
  bought it online) and look into previous purchases.

Comment: Something about the question makes me suspect that the OP wasn't the one to buy the ticket for her daughter and is now trying to find out how much it cost without the cooperation of whomever did pay for it. (Perhaps related to a custody battle? Or just to berate the daughter for wasting so-and-so much money on inessential travel?)

Comment: Agree with @HenningMakholm, I was going to comment "check your credit card bill" as a joke. It seems unlikely the OP would ask if they could do that.

Comment: This is the answer to some other question. The OP did not purchase the ticket; the OP's daughter did.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The question only says that the daughter was the passenger. Now, I imagine the question would have said something like "a flight I bought for my daughter" if the asker had paid but we don't actually know who bought the ticket.

Comment: Even if the OP bought the ticket *as part of a bigger package deal*, he/she might want to know "the actual price of the ticket" for some unspecified reason.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: If the OP had bought the ticket there is an extremely high possibility that this question would not have to be asked. We don't have to apply extreme heuristics to deduce that the question is a question other than one to which this is the answer. :)